# AWK : Apply user from each line of first column to the respective line's home directory of second column and iterate this until last record

Tags: awk

The out of the file is as follows:

```
[root@host ~]# cat manage.txt
ptest1 /home/ptest1
ptest2 /home/ptest2
ptest3 /home/ptest3
```

Here I wanted to get each user from each line of the first column and apply the same to their respective home directory in the second column, in its order.

I have already done using a simple bash:

```
[root@host ~]# num=$(wc -l manage.txt);count=1;for i in $(awk '{print $1}' manage.txt);do chown -Rh ${i}:${i} $(awk '{print $2}' manage.txt | head -${count} | tail -${count});count=$((count+1));done
```

I would like to know how this can be made simple and shorter using awk as I am in the learning phase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done in a simple Input_file reading itself, try following.

```
while read -r owner path
do
   echo chown -Rh  "$owner:$owner" "$path"
done < "manage.txt"
```

Above will print the commands, if you are happy with above then remove `echo` in above code.

---

In case you insist to do this in `awk` itself then try:

```
awk '{system("echo chown -Rh " $1":"$1 OFS $2)}' manage.txt
```

Above will also print commands on screen, if you are happy with commands printed then remove `echo` inside `system` and it should work then.

Answer (score 1):

You're reinventing `xargs`.

```
awk '{$1=$1":"$1}1' manage.txt | xargs -n 2 echo chown -Rh
```

If the output looks good, remove `echo`.